# Where is Make.sublime-build?

Tags: unix, sublimetext

I'm looking to the sublimetext build system, where I considering to customize my own build based on make.

Since there is `C.sublime-build` I was expecting to find `Make.sublime-build`. Where is it?

Comment: Did you run `locate Make.sublime-build` or `find / -name Make.sublime-build`?

Comment: yes for 2nd question, found nothing